# Find elements in a collection field Spring Data JPA Query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity contains a collection field

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SERVICE")
    public class Service {

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "SEQUENCE")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "SEQUENCE")
    @Column(name = "ID_SERVICE")
    private Integer id;

        @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "SERVICE_JOB",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_SERVICE", referencedColumnName = "ID_SERVICE"))
    @Column(name = "JOB")
    private List<String> jobs = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
```

I want to return services where field jobs contains my variable "job"

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT s FROM Service s WHERE ?1 in (s.jobs)")
List<Service> findByJob(String job);
```

It always returns an empty list although field jobs contains my variable

Any suggesstions?

Answer (score 5):

try a custom query where you can use `member of` like so :

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Service s WHERE ?1 member of s.jobs")
List<Service> findByJobs(String job)
```

Comment: I also tried this solution, but it returns an exception `nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

Comment: can you show us the full error please? beside what you annotate `private List<String> jobs`? can you show us the full code please

Comment: @GhizlaneLotfi can you explain what do you mean in your design did you mean that a service can have a list or other services?

Comment: A service has a list of jobs

Comment: @GhizlaneLotfi then your design is not correct, it should be `private List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();` no?

Comment: Job is not a Class, but a String

Comment: and where you store this list of strings?

Comment: In oracle database , `CREATE TABLE "SERVICE_JOB" (
  "ID_SERVICE" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
  "JOB" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("ID_SERVICE", "JOB") ENABLE,
  CONSTRAINT "FR_SERVICE_JOB" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_SERVICE") REFERENCES "SERVICE" ("ID_SERVICE") ENABLE
  );`

Comment: I can't see any list of string of jobs in your query

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way

```
@Query("select s from Service s WHERE :job in elements(s.jobs)")
List<Service> getAllByJobs(@Param("job") String job)
```

For this to work you have to change your Entity a bit, like this

```
public class Service {
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> jobs
}
```

Comment: I tried ur solution before I got this error `nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`